# C# - Send file using http to Linux directory

Tags: c#, apache, file, client-server

I would like my client software to send a file to my Linux server using http. This is my line

`WebClient client = new WebClient();
 client.UploadFile("http://192.168.121.128/musiclocation/", file);`

Where 'file' is the path of the file I would like to upload. When I run my code I receive the error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
>
> Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

I know my software CAN find the server because I have code elsewhere in my client that works perfectly fine (it does not throw an exception).

```
MusicPlayer.PlayMp3FromUrl("http://192.168.121.128/musiclocation/" + dataGridView1.Rows[rownumber].Cells["path"].Value.ToString());
```

My apache setup is default except for /musiclocation/ which is an alias to a directory in my home folder.

```
Alias /musiclocation/ /home/homefolder/MusicStorage/
<Directory /home/homefolder/MusicStorage/>
options +Indexes
order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Does apache need to be configured further to allow the WebClient upload through. Or am I misunderstanding how WebClient upload works in the first place? I'm most perplexed about why I'm getting a 404 error. I would expect 403 error at the least since I KNOW that my server is reachable.

Any comments or suggestions to help me troubleshoot this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `UploadFile` method can only send the data to a resource on the server, it can't take care of saving the data as a file on the server.

You are sending the data to a folder name on the server, but there is no resource on the server by that name that can receive the data. You need a page on the server that can get the data that is send in the request and save it as a file on the server.